# Setting and changing virtual paths in Artifactory

Tags: jnlp, artifactory, virtual-path, binary-repository

Does Artifactory (OSS, *not* enterprise version) provide a "**`latest-release`**" URI concept, where:

1. Perhaps I have `http://myartifactory.example.com/artifactory/simple/myrepo/myorg/mylib/1.0.0/mylib-1.0.0.jar` as a URI in Artifactory
2. Perhaps I also have `http://myartifactory.example.com/artifactory/simple/myrepo/myorg/mylib/latest-release` as a virtual/symlink-style URI **that is configured to point** to the 1.0.0 URI (above)

Does Artifactory support this concept? Moreover, does its REST API support changing where `latest-release` points on-the-fly?

---

**PLEASE NOTE:** My actual use case here is I need a non-changing URL to reference from inside a JNLP file (!) but want to be able to change what is served from that URL every time I "release" a new version of a Swing app.

Answer (score 0):

With the OSS version you can achieve this in kind of a hacky way by performing a [checksum deployment](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactbyChecksum).
Since Artifactory is using a checksum based storage, you can keep the same artifact in multiple paths without consuming additional storage space.
You can perform a checksum deployment of the latest artifact to a reserved path which will always be used for the latest artifact. The result will be another path pointing to this artifact - it will not consume extra storage and you will not need to deploy the actual bytes again.

To complete the picture, the Pro version provides a REST API for [retrieving the latest artifact version](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact).